# mpmovieplayercontroller Issues ipad

Tags: ipad

Hi i have created app for ipad , it has an video files in resource folder and it plays when the user click play button.
It works for first time user clicks play button but when user plays subsequent times of video file.The issues occurs that is the video is not  play only audio is playing.These issues occurs not randomly  but some more times it will occurs.

One more thing at the time of issue occurs (Video is not playing ) , when i click the wo-arrow icons located at the bottom right corner of the player the movie goes to full screen and it shows video .At the time video is playing.

Can any one help me ?

Here is my sample code

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

}
@property (readwrite, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
    @synthesize moviePlayer;

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  object:self.moviePlayer];
 [super viewDidLoad];
    }


    -(IBAction)PlayBtnPressed:(id)sender
{

 NSURL *movieURL;
 NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"title" ofType:@"mp4"];
 movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
 // Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL
 MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
 if (mp)
 {
  // save the movie player object
  self.moviePlayer = mp;
  [mp release];

  UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation];
  [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:orientation];
  // Play the movie!
  [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
  [self.moviePlayer play];
 }
}


     - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
   NSLog(@"movieFinishedCallback aNotification");
     MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   removeObserver:self
   name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:player]; 
    [player stop]; 
    [player.view removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

Thanks in advance ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the movieplayer is not getting released until after you've allocated a second one on the same movie file:

```
self.moviePlayer = mp;
```

retains it, but the movie finished part doesn't do a

```
self.moviePlayer = nil;
```

Could be that's causing you problems.